# Changing innerHTML of item nested inside another HTML item

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML item as follow:

```
<div id = "myTarget" class="myItem">
    <div class="nestedItem">0/0</div>       <!-- to be updated -->
</div>
```

I would like to update the content of `nestedItem` dynamically.  However, this JS code fails:

```
document.getElementById("myTarget").getElementsByClassName("nestedItem").innerHTML = "1/4";
```

Can someone tell me what went wrong?

Comment: [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: That said... Use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead

Comment: ^^ e.g., `document.querySelector("#myTarget .nestedItem").innerHTML = "...";`

Comment: Thank you, gentlemen!  I should try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `getElementsByClassName` returns an array like object with the elements what you need to iterate. From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName):

> The getElementsByClassName method of Document interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

Possible solution could be:

```js
const target = document.getElementById('myTarget');
const items = target.getElementsByClassName('nestedItem');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(items, e => e.innerHTML = '1/4');
```

```html
<div id="myTarget" class="myItem">
    <div class="nestedItem">0/0</div>
</div>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: My lord, you saved the day!